# getElementById failing on a valid div?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Puzzled... after executing the 10 lines of code below, `elem1` is defined, and `elem2` is null. However, the 2 blocks of code are identical, apart from the variable names, and the fact that one is creating an 'svg' node (which works) and the other is creating a 'div' node (which fails):

```
   var chart_name = "chart_" + ui.panel.id;
   var chart_elem = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
   chart_elem.setAttributeNS(null, "id", chart_name);
   top.appendChild(chart_elem);
   var elem1 = document.getElementById(chart_name);

   var pldiv_name = "plist_" + ui.panel.id;
   var pldiv_elem = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "div");
   pldiv_elem.setAttributeNS(null, "id", pldiv_name);
   top.appendChild(pldiv_elem);
   var elem2 = document.getElementById(pldiv_name);
```

If I set a breakpoint on the last line of code, before `getElementById` is called, Firebug shows me this HTML view:

```
<div id="tabs-2" class="etc...">
<svg id="chart_tabs-2">
<div id="plist_tabs-2">
</div>
```

In the DOM view, Firebug shows `elem1` with localName `svg`, and id `chart_tabs-2`. It's next sibling is a div, with id `plist_tabs-2`, which is the value of `pldiv_name`. Despite all this, `getElementById(pldiv_name)` fails.

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try creating the DIV *not* in the SVG namespace?

```
var pldiv_elem = document.createElement("div");
```

Comment: Yes, that's done it - thanks. I had assumed that all names were global, but obviously not. Can you tell me what's going on here?

Comment: In DOM, for `getElementById()` to work, the ID attribute for the particular schema to which an element belongs needs to be known. There is no assumption that it will always be an attribute that's called "id". You could define an XML schema where the ID attribute is called "foo". Therefore, since `<div>` doesn't belong to the SVG namespace, the ID attribute for this alien element cannot be known by DOM. Also, I suspect that there can be some browser-specific behaviour involved.

Comment: For additional insight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling your JavaScript. If it's "inline" but before your DIV, then the code will be executed before the HTML code is parsed and the DIV exists. You either need to move the code to after the DIVs, or execute it on the window load (or document ready) event.

Comment: You are right. I didn't read your code properly :-) But in that case, why are you using `getElementById`? When you create your DIV you already have a reference to it (`chart_elem` and `pldiv_elem`), so it's no need to get the same reference again using `getElementById`.

Comment: This was a cut-down test case - pldiv_name goes via Ajax to the server, which returns JS, which includes the 'getElementById' call.